# Sliding icon next to dynamic text with ellipsis

Tags: html, css, icons, css-float, ellipsis

I have a list of items and to the end of some items I want to add an icon (or several of them - it's dynamic). Items' container has a fixed width and if item's text size is too big - I'd like to add ellipsis.
So the problem is that icon is added next to text and if text is long - the icon moves off the container. The template for all items has to be the same.
**Note:** not all items have icons and some icons may have more than one icon.
**Note2:** javascript solution is not applicable, want to make it in pure CSS.

Actual:
[image]

Expected:
[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

```css
body {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.container {
  width: 150px;
  background: #ff0;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.container li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.item {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.icon {
  background: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="text">Text 1</span>
      <span class="icon">12</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="text">Text 2 Text 2</span>
      <span class="icon">12</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="text">Text 3 Text 3 Text 3</span>
      <span class="icon">12</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="text">Text 4 Text 4 Text 4</span>
      <span class="icon"></span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone still looking for solution I figured it out:

Markup:

```
<div class="block-wrap">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="text">Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
.block-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.icon {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 14px;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rezed/n1qft37L/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s7n9b9gb/1/)**

Fix the width for the text next to `.item class` and make `display as inline-block` to get floated with icon.
CSS:

```
.item {
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.item >span {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width:70%;
    display:inline-block;
}
.icon {
    background: #f00;
    display:inline-block;
    max-width:50px;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The problem is that the amount of icons is dynamic. So I can't set `max-width:50px;` to it. The same for text and `max-width:70%;`. There could be no icons at all and in that case text should be expanded to the whole item space.